# How to interact with command-line program using batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I would like to write a batch/cmd script to pass arguments to another command-line program.

However, I'd like to display the output of that program in the batch file, and be able to interact with the program normally.

Effectively, the batch file becomes a transparent way to access the program.

How do I do this?

Comment: Use the `expect` utility.

Comment: @stark I'd rather do it without any third-party software, if possible.

Comment: You might also check the internal [call](http://ss64.com/nt/call.html) command.

Comment: @Chinggis6 Thanks, it would be great if you can expand on this in an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't understand the question very clearly but `call` is the command that comes to my mind. It is an internal command being a feature of `cmd.exe` as external commands exist as separate executable files, usually in `%SystemRoot%\System32` folder.

`call` command executes other batch files (with `.bat` extension) within the *calling* script and may pass arguments to that external executable file assigned as to its parameters.

Moreover, call command may `call` for `label` (defined as `:MyLabel` inside the batch file, and otherwisely intended and working with `GOTO` command as points or sections in a batch file to switch the execution to, which is an old and might also be a wrong feature) within the script itself without referring to any external batch file.

The command is well documented in an SS64 [page](http://ss64.com/nt/call.html), and it's main difference from just calling the other script or executable file without any using any command, say as `MyScript.bat` or `MyExecutable.exe` is that it doesn't leave and exit the current script when calling or upon the external script's finishing, keeping it in the current session, and comes back to and continues executing the calling script's following lines, where the call is originated from.

Comment: I'm not using the feature for long, but that's what I remember from my experience of using it :)

Comment: I'm on Fedora, I cannot test it on Windows, but good examples are provided in the page as well as [here](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/call.php).

Comment: Could you add an example usage?