# Windows Batch-File to execute and communicate with running program

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file, process

(How) can a program with interactive command line mode (*shell*) be programmatically "interacted" with from CMD.exe via batch file (.bat)?
Example:

```
>program.exe
>>aCommand
>>someResponse
>>anotherCommand
>>someotherResponse
>>quit
>
```

The batch file should start `program.exe`, send `aCommand`, then [optionally] wait for `someResponse` and so on.

There's [How to interact with command-line program using batch file?](https://superuser.com/questions/1146573/how-to-interact-with-command-line-program-using-batch-file) but does not need automated interaction and so accepts `CALL` as answer.

Maybe it's possible to start the process separately and then pipe commands and responses to communicate with it?

---

Elsewhere:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15928325/controlling-interactive-console-programs-from-batch-file-cmd (suggests piping [from text file])
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5722605/automate-a-windows-command-line-utility-with-a-batch-file-send-keystrokes-to-s?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 2):

Various mechanisms exist for `.bat` files, although very limited.

[**Microsoft DOS set command**](https://www.computerhope.com/sethlp.htm)

Syntax : `SET /P variable=[promptString]`

Example :

```
ECHO 1. Print Hello
ECHO 2. Print Bye
ECHO 3. Print Test
set choice=
set /p choice=Type the number to print text.
```

[**Microsoft DOS choice command**](https://www.computerhope.com/choicehl.htm)

Syntax : `CHOICE [/C choices] [/N] [/CS] [/T timeout /D choice] [/M text]`

Example :

```
CHOICE /C YNC /M "Press Y for Yes, N for No or C for Cancel."
```

[**Pause command**](https://ss64.com/nt/pause.html)

Syntax : `pause`

Issues the message "Press any key to continue . . ." and waits for any key.

Comment: While that does not answer my question, it's very good to know! :-) `choice` works similarly to `set /p` but sets `errorlevel`. Here's another CMD reference: https://ss64.com/nt/choice.html

Comment: What would answer your question?

Comment: :-) If I knew, there would be no question.

Comment: These are the commands I do know. If you are looking for more sophistication, you will need to write a program that returns a number to the script via errorlevel.

Comment: I appreciate your effort but we seem to not understand each other. I've added to my question, hoping to make it clearer. Your answer does not seem to cover any communication with a separate program.

Comment: My above comment applies: You will need to write a program that is launched by the batch script in the background, that will send "aCommand" to program.exe, then terminate. An easy tool for that is [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/), where this can be written in a script of a few lines, then compiled to exe.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. How is it possible for `a program` to communicate with `program.exe` if it is not controlling it as a separate process, and why would I need a batch script at all? (In Python, I would use the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module to run and communicate with `program.exe`.)

Comment: By emulating key-strokes to the program, in fact acting as the keyboard.